# Javascript (ES6) Modules: Is it possible to export a variable with a dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

In ES6 I can export a simple `foo` constant:

```
export const foo = 1;
```

I can also convert the value of that export (`1`) to a variable, and export that:

```
const fooValue = 1;
export foo = fooValue;
```

But my question is, is there any way I can convert the **key** of the export (`foo`) in to a variable:

```
const fooLabel = 'foo';
const fooValue = 1;
export something(fooLabel) = fooValue;
```

Or do exports always have to explicitly named?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to use named exports. It's easy enough to export a single object with dynamically generated keys though:

```
let obj = {};

obj[fooLabel] = fooValue;

export default obj;
```

Comment: Right, but unfortunately then I can't do `import {foo} from 'obj'` :(

Comment: @machineghost - Nope. But you can import and then destructure it in another statement.

Comment: Yeah, not quite the interface I was hoping for, but hey it still it beats the crap out of ES5 (non-) imports